# Fast search through a N*M data structure?

Tags: java, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have the data: number[M][N], it's inputted through a stream, so I can put it whatever data structure I want.
I have to search through it many times using different pairs of short values. So I need to get numbers of rows using values in two columns.
I can create an additional array and use a binary search to find positions using it in inputted data, something like an index in a data base, but is there a standard libraries to solve a task like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put it into more than one data structure if the searching warrants this. You could have the data in a HashMap, TreeMap, and another Map that would have the key-value mapping the other way around (if that makes sense in your case).

What's the data like, and how do you need to search it?